# NameError: name 'x1' is not defined in OpenCV Python

Tags: python, opencv

My OpenCV (Python) code for detecting object:

```
import ...
face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
cap1 = cv2.VideoCapture(1)

while True:
    ret1, img1 = cap1.read()

    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img1, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)
    for (x1, y1, w1, h1) in faces:
            if x1 >0:
            detect_face1 = x1
            print 'face distance Camera 1: ', detect_face1
        else:
            pass
```

Debugger showing that `faces` is `type tuple: ()`, probably as a result showing `if x1 >0: NameError: name 'x1' is not defined`. Because if Face is detected in camera then `faces` is an array which has a x1 value > 0. I know it may be pretty simple fix, but any help is appreciated.

Comment: If `faces` is a tuple, then iterating over it the way you do is weird. For that loop to work `faces` would need to be **a list of** tuples.

Comment: At the beginning when no Face is detected, `faces`has no value for `x1,y1,w1,h1`, as a result I am guessing I am getting this error. when Face detected then `faces =[10,20,30,40]`  (say), and my loop works. But when it's empty I am getting this error. How can I overcome this? @deceze

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Tuple `faces` was empty, as a result having `NameError`.

```
if faces==0:
    pass
else:
    detect_face=x1
```

solved the problem.